# opened_files large, open_files tiny

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-tuning

on my mariadb server OPENED_FILES is currently 2,775,453 and OPEN_FILES never seems to exceed 65. I understand that opened_files is cumulative and is meaningless without a time period. UPTIME_SINCE_FLUSH_STATUS is 60,287.

When I work out the opened tables per hour (OPENED_FILES*3600/UPTIME_SINCE_FLUSH_STATUS) it is currently 165,735 but usually averages to 300,000. Obviously something isn't quite right.

Here are some of my parameters

```
OPEN_FILES_LIMIT = 10,162
TABLE_DEFINITION_CACHE = 1,000
TABLE_OPEN_CACHE = 5,000
```

my server hosts just under 1,000 tables and THREADS_CREATED = 121.

cat /proc/14883/limits gives me

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             64110                64110                processes
Max open files            10162                10162                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       64110                64110                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

some of the queries include

```
Count: 7  Time=0.35s (2s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=7.4 (52), 

Rows_examined=3626.3 (25384), user@localhost
  #
  # explain: id select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  posts   range   PRIMARY,type_status_date        type_status_date        N       NULL    N       Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  meta__order_tax ref     PRIMARY,post_id,post_id_key_value       PRIMARY N       mydb.posts.ID,const       N       Using where
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  meta__order_shipping_tax        ref     PRIMARY,post_id,post_id_key_value       PRIMARY N       mydb.posts.ID,const       N       Using where
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  meta__order_total       ref     PRIMARY,post_id,post_id_key_value       PRIMARY N       mydb.posts.ID,const       N       Using where
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  meta__order_shipping    ref     PRIMARY,post_id,post_id_key_value       PRIMARY N       mydb.posts.ID,const       N       Using where
  #
  SET timestamp=N;
  SELECT SUM( meta__order_total.meta_value) as total_sales,SUM( meta__order_shipping.meta_value) as total_shipping,SUM( meta__order_tax.meta_value) as total_tax,SUM( meta__order_shipping_tax.meta_value) as total_shipping_tax, posts.post_date as post_date FROM wp_posts AS posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta__order_total ON ( posts.ID = meta__order_total.post_id AND meta__order_total.meta_key = 'S' ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta__order_shipping ON ( posts.ID = meta__order_shipping.post_id AND meta__order_shipping.meta_key = 'S' ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta__order_tax ON ( posts.ID = meta__order_tax.post_id AND meta__order_tax.meta_key = 'S' ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta__order_shipping_tax ON ( posts.ID = meta__order_shipping_tax.post_id AND meta__order_shipping_tax.meta_key = 'S' )
  WHERE         posts.post_type         IN ( 'S' )
  AND   posts.post_status       IN ( 'S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S')
  AND   posts.post_date >= 'S'
  AND   posts.post_date < 'S'
  GROUP BY YEAR(posts.post_date), MONTH(posts.post_date), DAY(posts.post_date) ORDER BY post_date ASC
```

and

```
Count: 777  Time=0.00s (3s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows_sent=525.2 (408109), Rows_examined=5163.5 (4012019), c10_sql[c10_sql]@localhost
  #
  # explain: id select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  tt      ALL     PRIMARY,term_id_taxonomy,taxonomy       NULL    NULL    NULL    N       Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  t       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY N       mydb.tt.term_id   N
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  tm      ref     term_id,meta_key        term_id N       mydb.tt.term_id   N       Using where
  # explain: N  SIMPLE  tr      ref     PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id,term_taxonomy_id_object_id     term_taxonomy_id        N       mydb.tt.term_taxonomy_id  N       Using where; Using index
  #
  SET timestamp=N;
  SELECT  t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id, tm.meta_value FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta AS tm ON (t.term_id = tm.term_id AND tm.meta_key = 'S')  WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S') AND tr.object_id IN (N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N)  GROUP BY t.term_id, tr.object_id ORDER BY tm.meta_value+N ASC, t.term_order ASC
```

I've currently got

```
MAX_HEAP_TABLE_SIZE = 268,435,456
SORT_BUFFER_SIZE = 4,194,304
TMP_TABLE_SIZE = 268,435,456
```

tmp tables written to disk CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES*100/(CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES+CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES) averages 48% but if I make MAX_HEAP_TABLE_SIZE and TMP_TABLE_SIZE much bigger I can get it down to 47% (yah!)

The server has 16GB ram but also runs apache web server.

some optimisation attempts to date

```
--30-November-2018 performance changes

ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` CHANGE `meta_key` `meta_key` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD INDEX post_id_meta_key (meta_key,post_id);
ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` DROP INDEX `meta_key`;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD INDEX post_id_key_value (meta_key(50),post_id,meta_value(50));
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta ADD INDEX meta_value_key (meta_value(50),meta_key(50));
ALTER TABLE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ADD INDEX order_item_id_key_value (order_item_id,meta_key(50),meta_value(50));
ALTER TABLE wp_options ADD INDEX autoload (autoload);
ALTER TABLE wp_woocommerce_order_items ADD INDEX type_name (order_item_type, order_item_name(128));
ALTER TABLE wp_wfConfig ADD INDEX autoload (autoload);
ALTER TABLE wp_term_relationships ADD INDEX term_taxonomy_id_object_id (term_taxonomy_id,object_id);

--5-December-2018 performance changes

ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` CHANGE `meta_id` `meta_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key, meta_id);
ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` ADD UNIQUE `meta_id` (`meta_id`);
ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` CHANGE `meta_id` `meta_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--25-December-2018 performance changes

ALTER TABLE `wp_postmeta` CHANGE `meta_key` `meta_key` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `wp_terms` CHANGE `name` `name` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE `wp_terms` CHANGE `slug` `slug` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
ALTER TABLE `wp_termmeta` CHANGE `meta_key` `meta_key` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` CHANGE `meta_key` `meta_key` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
requested by Rick James,
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
apache configuration file, 
for server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Opened_files` also includes tmp tables needed for complex `SELECTs`.  What are the values of `Created_tmp_disk_tables` and `Created_tmp_tables`?  And how much RAM do you have?

Heck, simply provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES;`; there are probably other things to check.

We will probably need to look at some of the queries.  If you can identify one or two; provide them, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comments on the **ALTERs**

Index prefixing, such as `(meta_key(50),post_id,meta_value(50))` is generally useless.  The Optimizer cannot see past the first prefix to use the other columns.  Later you changed to `VARCHAR(60)`; time to get rid of the prefixing for `meta_key`.

`meta_id` -- Do you reference it in some other table?  If not, it is wasted.

Some columns are `CHARACTER SET utf8`, some are `utf8mb4`?  If you `JOIN` on inconsistent charsets, indexes can't be used.

For further fishing around for slow queries, turn on the slowlog, summarize it, and let's discuss it.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: CREATED_TMP_TABLES = 733,692
CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES = 690,566

This was asat yesterday with the 60K uptime

Comment: Is the `Uptime` still 60K?  10/second is rather high.  Also, the percentage that goes to disk is very high.  This won't quite 'prove' that the 2.7M comes from tmp tables, but is comes close.  Let's see one of those queries.

Comment: tmp tables is something I'm also working on. CREATED_TMP_DISK_TABLES is way too big. The biggest culprit seems to be wordpress. I would expect a system with such a huge user base to have more optimised queries.

Comment: Whenever you fetch `meta_value`, which is `LONGTEXT`, you will need a temp table on disk.  Meanwhile, here are some tips on speeding up `wp_postmeta`: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: so even if you don't sort by the long text, it will still need a tmp table?

Comment: Without `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns (and other situations), the temp table will be in memory, not disk.  Usually (not always), `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `UNION` cause temp table (on disk or not).

Comment: @DanielGarcia - I added to my Answer.

Comment: meta_id appears a number of times in the wordpress code. I'm surprised the Speeding up wp_postmeta article recommended it be removed.

I can't imagine meta_key being compared with a different charset it a join. I can imagine something like this

    select *
    from wp_posts 
    join wp_postmeta on wp_postmeta.post_id=wp_posts.id and wp_postmeta.meta_key='some literal'

Comment: @DanielGarcia - I don't speak WP, so I can't imagine needing `meta_id` in any other table.  Removing it decreases the table size and allows something better to be 'clustered', namely PK(post_id, meta_key) (such as the select in your Comment).  The charset came to mind when I saw your Alters -- some had utf8, some had utf8mb4.